# How to create dynamic column chart in excel using java poi or jfree jar

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls, xlsx

i need to create a dynamic column chart in excel report compare with 2 columns values(sale and margin) based on selected dates. already i am generating excel report using poi's WriteableWork object. but i need to generate the charts dynamically.

this method is to create excel report

```
public String excelReport() throws ParseException, IOException {
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    WritableWorkbook w = Workbook.createWorkbook(bos);
    WritableSheet sheet = w.createSheet("Page 1", 0);
    // Create Filename
    String filenameDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
    attachmentName = "attachment; filename=\"test".xls\"" ;

            int headerCol = 0;
            addBoldCell(sheet, headerCol++, 0, "Date");
            addBoldCell(sheet, headerCol++, 0,"Sale");
            addBoldCell(sheet, headerCol++, 0,"Margin");
     int row = 1;
     int col = 0;
             addNumberCell(sheet, col++, row, date);
             addNumberCell(sheet, col++, row, 20000);
         addNumberCell(sheet, col++, row, 500); 

    w.write();
    w.close();
    bufferSize = bos.size();
    fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());

} catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("Error creating an Excel file.", e);
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
        }
    }
}
return SUCCESS;
}
```

In struts.xml

```
<action name="excelReport" method="excelReport" class="com.test.action.ReportAction">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">${attachmentName}</param>
            <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">${bufferSize}</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Excel Report i am getting succesfully, i want chart for this excel values like below sample chart

[image]

i tried with some poi and jfree samples but not getting solution.